# Page by Page Navigation with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

Following the address here http://pastebin.com/icrLP0Ej one is able to scrape the results of http://www.etsy.com/search?q=hello%20kitty

My question is, using PhantomJS, how is one able to properly navigate to the other remaining pages using the numbered page links. Please note that a wait would have to be implemented to avoid weighing down the server.  Also,  if possible, how is one able to download the images. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use PhantomJS for this? There is absolutely no need to render client side code to access the contents of this page. What language are you using for this? I can post a solution written in Ruby if you are interested.

Comment: I work with Python. If the Ruby code can be converted to Python version, please send it, thanks.